# Elasticsearch: sort by copy_to target of two fields

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm using trying to create a `fullName` using `copy_to` exactly like docs say to do: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

But, what I want to do in a query, is to sort by `fullName`. However, when I specify the field to sort I see that the query is actually sorted by `forename`, e.g. the first part of `copy_to`:

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "<nested>.fullName.keyword": {
                "nested_path": "<nested>",
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

What I want to do is to sort by `forename` + `surname` e.g. by full `fullName`.

Is it possible to do this using `copy_to` at all?

Comment: Based on my observation .. Copy_to is not storing "Test Name" as a single keyword in your case, instead it is storing them as multiple keywords "Test" & "Name", hence the issue. Same can be asserted by searching for "Test","Name" & "Test Name".

Comment: Yep, it looks like that. The problem is I need to "sort", not to search. So I decided to go with additional index instead